# Find element and replace its outerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to replace element's html code. It looks like that:

```
<a class="disp_img" onclick="increase('\x6c\x6f\x61\x64\x5f\x6d\x65\x6e\x75\x28\x24\x28\x27\x23\x69\x6d\x61\x67\x65\x73\x27\x29\x2e\x68\x74\x6d\x6c\x28\x29\x2c\x20\x24\x28\x27\x23\x69\x6d\x61\x67\x65\x73\x5f\x32\x27\x29\x2e\x68\x74\x6d\x6c\x28\x29\x2c\x20\x27\x72\x61\x6e\x64\x6f\x6d\x27\x2c\x20\x27\x73\x74\x72\x69\x63\x74\x27\x29');" href="javascript:void(0);">Display Images</a>
```

this is:

```
 'load_menu($('#images').html(), $('#images_2').html(), 'random', 'strict')'
```

but it needs to stay HEX.

I just want to replace "random" with "strict", like this:

```
var found = [];
var changed = [];
var c = 0;
var searchText = "Display Images";

var as = document.getElementsByClassName("disp_img");
for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
    if (as[i].innerText == searchText){
    found[c] = as[i].outerHTML;
        c++;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {
    changed[i] = found[i].toString();
    changed[i] = changed[i].replace("\x27\x72\x61\x6e\x64\x6f\x6d\x27\x2c\x20\x27\x73\x74\x72\x69\x63\x74\x27", "\x27\x73\x74\x72\x69\x63\x74\x27\x2c\x20\x27\x73\x74\x72\x69\x63\x74\x27");
    console.log(changed[i]);
}
```

I can manage the rest, but I have troubles with this one.
How to use `replace` method correctly to replace that string?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I understand. I need to double backslashes, like `.replace("\\x27\\x72\\x61` etc.

Comment: Definitely not. Why would you ask to delete it??